# MYSQL Update all values with the value of an specific row

Tags: mysql

How can I achieve something like this:

UPDATE products SET description = **((  description of the row id 15  ))**

It means all rows will have the same description of the product number 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, use a `join`:

```
UPDATE products p cross join
       (select description
        from products
        where rowid = 15
       ) p15
   SET p.description = p15.description;
```

EDIT:

The subquery isn't necessary.  I just think it makes the query more readable.  It should have minimal impact on performance, because presumably it only returns one row.  You could write this as:

```
UPDATE products p join
       products p15
       on p15.rowid = 15
   SET p.description = p15.description;
```

Comment: Is a subquery necessary?